# Reduce/compress screensaver file size

Tags: screensaver, windows-screensaver

I have to produce a screensaver for a client who wants to install it across branches. Due to bandwidth limitations the screensaver needs to be below 500KB filesize. Actual screensaver content is about 200KB. Most of the screensaver utilities I tried seem to add a over head of 1-1.5MB over and above the actual content.

They have shared a .SCR done by other developer which is 400KB in size. Can anyone please share the info about achieving this?

Comment: have you tried compressing the `.scr` with [UPX](http://upx.sourceforge.net/) or a similar tool?

Answer (score 1):

You could try compressing the `.scr` file with [UPX](http://upx.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Thanks, I tried using UPX on a SCR that has just one small jpg. SCR size is 1.4MB. I get the message 'already packed by UPX' exception. It seems the software I am using is doing the compression already. It's strange because the jpg size id 50KB and SCR is 1.5 MB?

Answer (score 0):

`.scr` files are just renamed `.exe` files, so you don't have to use a special tool - you can create one by writing a windows program in whichever programming language you prefer.

They have to accept certain command line parameters:

- `/s` – Start the screensaver in full-screen mode.
- `/c` – Show the configuration settings dialog box.
- `/p ####` – Display a preview of the screensaver using the specified window handle.

There's an example C# project here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686421.aspx